# select from an abitrary set

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a shorthand way of creating an arbitrary set and performing Linq on it?

i.e. I have a bunch of objects all of the same type but not currently in any kind of collection - they are all in separate variables.

```
(from a in new List<MyType>() { A, B, C, D} select a.Max).Max();
```

In my example the class `MyType` has a `Max` property and I want to find the max of all the `Max` properties of objects A, B, C and D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the compiler infer the collection type if all of the elements are of the same type:

```
(from a in new [] { A, B, C, D} select a.Max).Max();
```

and/or do the member selection in the `Max` call instead of the `Select`:

```
(new [] { A, B, C, D}).Max(i => i.Max);
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally just use an array.

```
new [] { A, B, C, D }.Max(x => x.Max)
```